# How to use CreateItemAsync to add an item with a list to an Azure gremlin DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

I am new to Azure Gremlin and I am trying to insert an item to the database that includes a list using Container.CreateItemAsync with Microsoft.Azure.Cosmo in C#.

Reading around I tried this. First, I have a class.

```
public class MyItem
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "myList")]
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

Then I run

```
MyItem item = new MyItem
{
    Id = "myItemId",
    MyList = new List<string> { "value1", "value2", "value3" }
};

container.CreateItemAsync(item);
```

This creates a new item in the database but completely ignores the list.
I don't want to insert the list as text but rather as a property that holds an actual list.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share an example of how the document looks once inserted? Newtonsoft.Json should be serializing "MyList" as an array of strings.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta, yes, it looks like this:
[
  {
    "id": "myItemId",
    "label": "NativeVertex",
    "type": "vertex"
  }
]
It looks like it completely ignores the list

Answer (score 0):

You used to debug getter setter which proper command.
Try using collection class

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).